# What are the 10 kinyanim with buying and selling?

Tags: halacha, transactions, business

Can someone please provide for me a list of the 10 kinyanim with their names in Hebrew? I can't find one anywhere! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Land**:

1. כסף
2. שטר
3. חזקה

**Objects**:

4. משיכה
5. הגבהה
6. יד
7. חצר

   7.1 ד׳ אמות
8. חליפין - שוה בשוה
9. חליפין - סודר
10. אגב קרקע
11. סיטומתא

**Kiddushin**:

[1 & 2; כסף & שטר]

12. ביאה

Comment: I didn't include the 48 קניני תורה.

Comment: do you mind to write it out in Hebrew?

Comment: Where did you get the number 10 from?

Comment: this book on the Rambam I was using.

Comment: Meshichah and Hagbahah are really two forms of the same thing, and likewise the two Chalipin’s. That might be where 10 comes from.

Comment: Mesira,............mitat hayabam